# How to write an async function

Tags: javascript, angular, async-await

I am trying to download files from firebase bucket and store them to database. I want the download function to work async, so that a file download completes and pushes to array before the next file in the files array`(this.outPutFiles)` is downloaded and pushed to array`(this.img_array)`. I tried this but it's not working as I expect

```
async getFiles(e){
  this.outPutFiles = e;
  await Promise.all(_.map(this.outPutFiles, file => 
     this._storage.ref(file).getDownloadURL().subscribe(url =>  this.img_array.push(url))
  ));

}
```

Comment: what exactly are you expecting from this function?

Comment: Check out the async library as it does EXACTLY what you want and is easy to get started with - http://caolan.github.io/async/

Answer (score 0):

Store these download URLs that you're getting in an array.

Something like this:

```
downloadUrls = [];
imageUrls = [];
```

Inside your `getFiles` function push the `getDownloadURL()` in your `downloadUrls` array. Something like this:

```
getFiles(e){
  this.outPutFiles = e;
  Promise.all(_.map(this.outPutFiles, file => 
     this.downloadUrls.push(this._storage.ref(file).getDownloadURL());
  ));
}
```

Now apply a forkJoin on the `downloadUrls` array. Something like this:

```
forkJoin(this.downloadUrls).subscribe(latestValues => this.imageUrls = _.sortBy(latestValues));
```

`forkJoin` needs to be imported like this if you're using the Latest Version of Rxjs:

```
import { forkJoin } from 'rxjs/observable/forkJoin';
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the approach I generally take to achieving sequential async requests, maybe this can be helpful. Push your async functions to an array and then loop through that array asynchronously.

```js
const fn1 = () => {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            resolve('fn1')
        }, 3000)
    })
}

const fn2 = () => {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            resolve('fn2')
        }, 2000)
    })
}

const fn3 = () => {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            resolve('fn3')
        }, 1000)
    })
}

const results = []
let myArr = [fn1, fn2, fn3]

const asyncGet = async (fns)=> {
    for (const fn of fns) {
        await fn()
        .then(result=>results.push(result))
    }
}


asyncGet(myArr)
    .then(() => console.log(results))
    .catch(err=>console.log(err))
```